# Formatting inconsistent datetime variable

Tags: r, date, datetime, format

I have a large dataset (a few millions observations) that contains a datetime variable with an inconsistent format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ;  "%m/%d/%Y and %H:%M:%S".

Here is how the dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:6), 
   var2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
   datetime = c("2013-07-01 00:00:02", "2016-07-01 00:00:01", 
            "9/2/2014 00:01:20", "9/1/2014 00:00:25",
            "1/1/2015 0:07", "6/1/2015 0:01"))
```

Is there an efficient way to format the datetime variable into a unique, consistent date time format?

Comment: If you didn't have ambiguous dates (such as 9/2/2014), you could use `anytime` from the anytime package. As it is, you can only use `as.POSIXct` with all formats you have in your data and merge the results into one vector

Answer (score 3):

You can use lubridate package like this.

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(x = df$datetime, c("ymd HMS","mdy HMS"))

[1] "2013-07-01 00:00:02 UTC" "2016-07-01 00:00:01 UTC" "2014-09-02 00:01:20 UTC"
[4] "2014-09-01 00:00:25 UTC" NA                        NA                       
Warning message:
 2 failed to parse. 

lubridate::parse_date_time(x = df$datetime, c("ymd HMS","mdy HMS","mdy HM"))

[1] "2013-07-01 00:00:02 UTC" "2016-07-01 00:00:01 UTC" "2014-09-02 00:01:20 UTC"
[4] "2014-09-01 00:00:25 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:07:00 UTC" "2015-06-01 00:01:00 UTC"
```

> You can specify your date-time formats as needed, you may compare two examples I mentioned.

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`POSIXCT` solution using `parse_date_time`.

EDIT: incorporating @Akarsh Jain's `POSIXCT` formatting for better time alignment.

```
df$new_date <- parse_date_time(df$datetime, c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

Comment: Yeah... I was about to post this `df$datetime <- parse_date_time(df$datetime, c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))`

Comment: I just posted the same @D.sen. Coincidentally. I hope you won't mind.

Comment: ^ This is a better answer as I'm realizing that my solution is adapting the 7 mins to 7 secs.

Comment: Yeah ! (Y), just slight improvement.